# Editing race condition?

Tags: bug, editing

OP and I both edited [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1104979/301745) at the exact same second. My revision is shown, but the [revision history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1104979/revisions) says OP's is the most recent.

I think this is a bug, since the most recent revision should show, no? It seems like a race condition.

Comment: [possibly related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302258/edit-conflicts-during-a-re-edit-within-the-5-minute-window-can-create-an-erroneo)?